# How I can get data from table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have aspx page.  I dislay data in table. How I can get new values from this table in Controller. Or how I can generate grid/table another method in aspx page in mvc?

```
    <table id="Products" class="Products">
      <tr>
        <th>ProductId</th>
        <th>Productname</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>UnitPrice</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (var item in Model.NorthOrderDetails)
       {
           %>
            <tr>
        <td><%: item.ProductID %></td>
        <td><%: item.ProductName %></td>
        <td><%: Html.TextBox("Quantity",item.Quantity) %></td>
        <td><%: Html.TextBox("UnitPrice",item.UnitPrice) %></td>
        <td> <%: Html.ActionLink("Update", "View2") %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

Comment: You need a `for` loop (not a `foreach` loop) - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.NorthOrderDetails.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NorthOrderDetails[i].Quantity) .....}` so the controls are correctly named with indexers and can be bound to your collection on post back

Comment: @StephenMuecke.Ok, thanks. and how I can send new values to method View2 in my controller, if I have this method and it shows this table?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically add new items in the view?

Comment: No. update values in textboxes

Comment: If you use a `for` loop as I have shown, and you post back the model it will be correctly bound. You have not shown any controller methods or the models so its hard to see what else you may be doing wrong if its not working

Comment: @StephenMuecke. Ok. I understand. But if I have update record in DB I must get update values from textboxes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The table should be wrapped in a form. Each text box should have a unique 'id' attribute. This can be done with a few simple changes to your code.

Something like this:

```
<form>
<table id="Products" class="Products">
  <tr>
    <th>ProductId</th>
    <th>Productname</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>UnitPrice</th>
</tr>
<% foreach (var item in Model.NorthOrderDetails)
   {
       %>
        <tr>
    <td><%: item.ProductID %></td>
    <td><%: item.ProductName %></td>
    <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Quantity) %></td>
    <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.UnitPrice) %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
<button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Let us know if this helps!

Comment: It helps. I find another syntax, but its correct, too

Comment: Another great option (if you're familair with Javascript) is to use a library called Knockout.js. It makes binding to data on the client-side very easy. You can see some examples here: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html

Comment: I need write code without js. May you know how I can create a grid without js and table?

Comment: Some people love it, some people hate it, but Bootstrap provides out-of-the-box grid system which makes it very easy to build up a responsive grid of data.  But why do you not want to use an HTML table? If it's tabular data then a table is an acceptable way to do it.

Comment: If a table is ok to use, then the approach you have is ok.

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop. Not only does it generate duplicate `id` attributes (contradicting you own advice) it generates duplicate name attributes and will not be able to bind to the model. And you don't even give the form an `action` action attribute! (use `@Html.BeginForm())`

Comment: Yes - correct on the first point. However, I wasn't providing a working code sample, just showing that it needed a form. That's why I said 'something like this'. Just so you know, a form does not NEED an action. It will post back to the same action or if you're using ajax it can be set in the ajax call.